# Symmetry between integrals including absolute value

Tags: integral, calculus

So I came across below symmetry in my probability course that I can't understand.

[image]

I understand how the lower bound changes when removing the absolute value operator, but how does the 2 disappear?

Comment: Draw the graphs of the integrands.  Sketch in the areas represented by the integrals.  The result will be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left hand you have the integral of a function of $|v|$ (considering the quadratic term too), hence that function is symmetric on $v$'s domain. This comes simply from the fact that $f(|-v|) = f(|v|)$.

Integrating that function on positive values of $v$ yields the same result as integrating it on negative values of $v$, so, to compute the whole integral, it is sufficent to only perform the integral on positive $v$ and to double it (if you don't you will 
not account for negative $v$).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Just for clarification, when you say "to double it", do you mean that I have to multiply the integral by 2, when changing the domain and removing the absolute value operator?

Comment: yes.___________